# Crear una ruta relativa a un script linux y windows

Tags: linux, windows, script, consola

Me pusieron esto
"Desarrollar un script que se ejecute con la línea de comandos (una ruta relativa al script) e imprima en consola (console.log) los resultados a las preguntas:..."

Pero no tengo ni idea de como hacer la ruta relativa al script, o sea se hacer el script pero no tengo ni idea de la ruta relativa, ni si quiera por donde empezar.
gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola, @Jefferson. Una ruta relativa es algo como esto: `./ruta/destino/`, donde `./` es el directorio actual. Otro ejemplo de ruta relativa es éste: `../ruta/destino/`, donde `../` es también una relativa que apunta a un directorio padre. Mientras que una ruta absoluta es algo como esto: `/ruta/destino`, donde `/` indica el directorio raíz del sistema.

Comment: Hola david, entonces si quisiera crear un script lo que tendría que hacer es simplemente esto, por ejemplo:
./script?

Comment: Tienes que darme más contexto.